# Socket.io fails with an internal error

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I recently ran and npm install, which updated all my packages. For some reason, this broke my webserver (whenever I try to load a page it only loads part way and dies with this error). I tried rolling back versions of socket.io, redis, and nodetime, which are the packages that show up in the stacktrace, but I've had no luck in getting the webserver to work again. Help? I'm running on OS X.

```
events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
TypeError: First argument must be a Buffer
    at RedisClient.message (/Users/jchu/code/python/agles/ci/web/back/node_modules/socket.io/lib/stores/redis.js:126:24)
    at RedisClient.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/Users/jchu/code/python/agles/ci/web/back/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:440:22)
    at RedisReplyParser.<anonymous> (/Users/jchu/code/python/agles/ci/web/back/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:81:14)
    at RedisReplyParser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at RedisReplyParser.add_multi_bulk_reply (/Users/jchu/code/python/agles/ci/web/back/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:311:14)
    at RedisReplyParser.send_reply (/Users/jchu/code/python/agles/ci/web/back/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:272:18)
    at RedisReplyParser.execute (/Users/jchu/code/python/agles/ci/web/back/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:222:22)
    at RedisClient.on_data (/Users/jchu/code/python/agles/ci/web/back/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:358:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/jchu/code/python/agles/ci/web/back/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:93:14)
```

Comment: That looks like a pretty typical redis error, and probably implies that an API changed.  Not sure why rolling back didn't help.  How did you roll them back?  Have you examined all of your socket.io calls for API changes?  Its pretty hard to debug this with no code.  Your current and old versions of socket.io would also probably be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install MsgPack?
After I used

```
npm install msgpack
```

Socket.IO would show me the exact error you posted.

I uninstalled MsgPack via

```
npm uninstall msgpack
```

and everything worked just fine again.
This is not the solution to the problem, but it is a workaround to get your system back running.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MsgPack is required in my project so I couldn't use the answer listed here.

Instead, I found this page:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

Which led me to these code changes.

Previously I had:

```
redis = require('redis'),
redisPub = redis.createClient(),
redisSub = redis.createClient(),
redisClient = redis.createClient(),
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express),
sessionStore = new RedisStore({
  client: redisClient
}),
socketRedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis'),
socketRedis = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis'),

...

io.configure(function() {
  io.set('log level', 1);
  io.set('store', new socketRedisStore({
    redisPub: redisPub,
    redisSub: redisSub,
    redisClient: redisClient
  }));
  io.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {

...
```

Into this:

```
redis = require('redis'),
redisPub = redis.createClient(),
redisSub = redis.createClient(null, null, {detect_buffers: true}),
redisClient = redis.createClient(),
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express),
sessionStore = new RedisStore({
  client: redisClient
}),
socketRedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis'),
socketRedis = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis'),

...

io.configure(function() {
  io.set('log level', 1);
  io.set('store', new socketRedisStore({
    redis: redis,
    redisPub: redisPub,
    redisSub: redisSub,
    redisClient: redisClient
  }));
  io.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {

...
```

Note the inclusion of the options in the redisSub, to detect buffers, and then the injection of the base redis object into the socket.io store configuration.